# Why can't we send mail through mail function when website is in localhost?

Tags: php

I know we can do it with phpmailer but I have a requirement of doing it without using phpmailer or any other such classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is your local machine then chances are that its is not configured to send or receive mails

I have also faced same kind of problem and I solved it by this tutorial ::

http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-with-gmail-and-ssmtp/